# ms dynamics crm 2015 web resources html body onload function

Tags: javascript, html, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I added an easy navigation link at my custom entity. This link calls a web resource::

```
<script> function TweetOnLoad(){ var tweetWord = window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_name").getValue(); var dynamicUrl ="http://localhost:3000/?tw="+tweetWord ; location.href = dynamicUrl; } </script> 

body onload="TweetOnLoad()"
```

But there is a problem: I couldn't call the `TweetOnLoad` function on body tag, because crm doesn't allow. How can I handle this problem?

Comment: What is the error you are getting (crm doesn't allow)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this an iFrame/WebResource, if so, you are probably better off to pass a URL parameter of the "new_name" attribute.

From what you have though, move the JavaScript to the end of the HTML body tag and then call your function.

```
function TweetOnLoad(){ 
   var tweetWord = window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_name").getValue(); 
   var dynamicUrl ="http://localhost:3000/?tw="+tweetWord; 
   location.href = dynamicUrl; 
}

TweetOnLoad();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call it with settimeout function like

**setTimeout(TweetOnLoad,1000);**

and you can give a average milisecond value.

Also you can try to bind your function on another widget or something ' s event.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably limited by the cross-frame boundaries of communication. The proper way to implement this would be to use [`Window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), having a script both on the entity's form and in your custom webresource (presumably a HTML page with javascript) that knowingly (in a well-defined way) communicate with eachother.